# Laravel - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, voyager

I'm setup homestead in my pc then i'm try to access my files via local domain. But when i'm trying to connect with DB then showing me this error. I can't access my others projects too. I setup everything very well. But i don't know why showing me this error.

**Note:** I'm using windows 8.1

Here is my setup code:

1. Homestead.yaml

---

ip: "192.168.10.10"

memory: 2048

cpus: 1

provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:

```
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

folders:

```
- map: F:/xampp/htdocs/Projects
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects
```

sites:

```
- map: govt-university.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects/govt-university/public

- map: voyager.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects/voyager/public

- map: evaluationplus.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects/laravel-evaluationplus/public

- map: laravel-university.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects/laravel-evaluationplus/public
```

databases:
    - homestead

---

2. Host file

   ```
   192.168.10.10 govt-university.dev

   192.168.10.10 voyager.dev

   192.168.10.10 evaluationplus.dev

   192.168.10.10 laravel-university.dev
   ```

---

3. ENV file

   APP_NAME= Laravel

   APP_ENV=local

   APP_KEY=base64:nmcR0V2cbq+26H3EBdLmYRQN5bkiOryROTxHpvUzuvA=

   APP_DEBUG=true

   APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug

   APP_URL=http://voyager.dev

   DB_CONNECTION=mysql

   DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

   DB_PORT=3306

   DB_DATABASE=voyager

   DB_USERNAME=homestead

   DB_PASSWORD=secret

---

Error Image:
[image]

**Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks**

Comment: it is showing that there is no tables in your database. check your database again or try to migrate/seed tables.

Comment: Hi Witch, Thanks for your reply, I have table in my database (http://prntscr.com/gtgbdf)

Comment: can you please show me your settings model?

Comment: Here it is (http://prntscr.com/gtgdq2)

Comment: try changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was try localhost but it's not work...

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you migrated this database in Homestead and not on your local machine?

Comment: Hi Marcin, Thanks for your reply, What do you mean by Homestead database not loacl machine? I'm using mysql for my database system. This is from xampp server.

Comment: What's your table name and whats the corresponding model name ?

Comment: Hi Partho, Thanks for your reply. I have may tables and model. Here is all table name (http://prntscr.com/gtoyxp) & model (http://prntscr.com/gtozzj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ssh into Vagrant and then run artisan command to migrate database. Once you do this will be fixed.

Comment: Hi Manzurul, Thanks for your ans. Wow that's it, after running 'php artisan migrate' commend into Vagrant ssh then errors are gone. Would you describe me why this happening Please...

Comment: Vagrant use virtualbox to setup the development environment which is why it create the mysql server inside its container which can be accessed via ssh. It also mounts your project directory to its server www/htdocs/your-project folder too. Thats why artisan migrate command in your local directory wont migrate database because the environment vagrant created is fully isolated from your local machine. I hope its clear.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans. Of course, I have table in my database. There is no problem with migrate.

Comment: @MDIyasinArafat So when you run `php artisan migrate:status` what's the result?

Comment: Hi Marcin, Thanks for your reply, Here it is (http://prntscr.com/gtm9fw)